# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, opencv

I have an image (480,640,3) and I am trying to resize it to (150,150,1). Since my Keras model has been trained on images of shape (150,150,1), unfortunately I cannot seem to resize it using the PIL library. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

This is the code I am using right now:

The error is caused on the line `image5.resize()`

```
    stream.seek(0)
    data = numpy.fromstring(stream.getvalue() , dtype = numpy.uint8)
    image5 = cv.imdecode(data , 1)
    print(image5.shape)
    #cv.imwrite('uhhu.png',image5)
    img = image5.resize((150,150,1 ), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    cv.imwrite('hhh.png',img)
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
    x = x/255
    x = numpy.array(x)
    print(x.shape)
    #score = loaded_model.predict(img)
    #print(score)
```

Comment: I think you should specify exactly which line is causing the error.

Comment: I'm not much of a Python user but what happens if you change `(150,150,1)` to `(150,150)`? I think you might need to change the depth separately.

Comment: Initially it was 150,150 . Hence i changed it to 150,150,1 since that was the final shape i needed of the image

Comment: Is your image in color? maybe you could try changing the depth by using RGB2Gray conversion

Comment: Pillow documentation (which is a fork of PIL) states that "A new PIL.Image.LANCZOS constant was added instead of ANTIALIAS.". You could try to check if this is true to PIL as well.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is to resize using openCV instead of using PIL and specifying the appropriate pixel width and height.

```
img = cv.resize(image5 , (150,150))
```